# How to understand the grammar of "This is what Dumbledore sends his defender!"

Tags: sentence-construction

> "**This is what Dumbledore sends his defender**! A songbird and an old hat! ..."

I don't understand the grammar of that sentence because it engaged two objects for the verb **sends**: *what* and *his defender*. Maybe, ***This is the defender that Dumbledore sends*** looks more reasonable. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But there is no comma after 'sends'. 'the defenders' are the people Dumbledore is sending something to, in this case, a songbird and an old hat.

Comment: So, you meant "his defender" refers to 'Harry' in this case. I see it. Originally, I thought "his defender" refers to "A songbird and an old hat". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the preposition "to" has been omitted. I guess that Dumbledore's defender is Harry, I don't remember exactly, and he has sent to him a songbird and an old hat.

There are multiple questions about this subject in relation with the verb **send** in the *English Language and Usage* site.

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/410513/217656

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/372235/217656